# Maple 18 : I am unable to take definite integral of a complex integral

Tags: maple

```
int(sqrt(Pi^2*(cos(Pi*t)-2*sin(2*Pi*t))^2+9*Pi^2*sin(3*Pi*t)^2), t = -1 .. 0);
```

Error, (in int) wrong number (or type) of arguments: invalid options or option values passed to exact integration

Comment: Your code appears to be valid syntax. (Maple's inability to compute an exact result should not induce that error message.) I suggest trying the indefinite integration examples reported in the following link (and in the further links in my answer there), to try and ascertain whether you have a corrupt product installation. If you do then contact support@maplesoft.com for a link to download a new and  valid installer. Also let them know how you got your current installer; maybe they can figure out a common aspect. http://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/203393-Maple-18-Does-Not-Integrate

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in Maple 18.

```
> int(sqrt(Pi^2*(cos(Pi*t)-2*sin(2*Pi*t))^2+9*Pi^2*sin(3*Pi*t)^2), t = -1 .. 0);
                                                                    0
                                                                   /
                                                                  |      2                            2       2            2 1/2
                                                                  |   (Pi  (cos(Pi t) - 2 sin(2 Pi t))  + 9 Pi  sin(3 Pi t) )    dt
                                                                  |
                                                                 /
                                                                   -1

> evalf(%);
                                                                                            8.959334516
```